# Measure Clicks using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, onclick, modal-dialog

Fairly new to using JS and I have created an image that brinks up a popup modal upon clicking it. I am following an example on w3schools.com, but I wish they would explain this one aspect of their code. So the popup modal contains an "x" that upon clicking, will close out of the modal as it should. However, when they create the variable in JS for the cancel button, they have it followed by a 0 in brackets:

```
var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]; 
                                                           ^
                                                           ^
```

My first question is, what do you refer to this part that contains a numeric value? Is this an array? And is this used to measure how many clicks are being recorded (i.e. upon clicking, this value will change to [1]?).

Furthermore, Is it possible for me to append another variable in place of that value? In other words if it possible for me to do the following?

```
var clicks = [0];
var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("close").clicks;
```

I would like to know this because I want to see that if the button is clicked, I would to use the same cancel button on other modals in the same website. By this, I mean that I would like change the click value back to [0], so it would work the same for other modals (as of now, the cancel button only works on the first modal, and it does not close out the other ones. I believe it is because I am not going back to [0]).

Apologies on not using the correct terminology; That is one of the main reasons why I am asking this. What is that value in brackets [0] referred to? Is it measuring clicks? And how can I keep changing its value so that it is back to [0] when I want to perform the same action on other modals? Any and all help would be much appreciated as I am quite new to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

"getElemetsByClassName" will return an Array. By using "[0]" at the end, it's just saying that I want to store on closeButton the first position of this array.

If there's only one ".close" on the page, the return will be ->> [element].
If there's more than one ->> [element, element...]

Comment: Thanks a ton. Just to clarify, would this mean that I could essentially have multiple names in there? For example, is it possible to do the following: var secondCloseButton = document.getElementByClassName("close","close2","close3")[1]; ? I am just confused as to why my button only works on one of the three places I need it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The function **getElementsByClassName[name]** returns an array of all elements having **[name]** as class name. Because there is only one element with this specific class name in this example (or they know they only need the first element of the array) the index [0] is appended, returning the first element of this array. Therefore it makes no sense to change the index except you create more elements using the class "close". Also, the index has nothing to do with the count of clicks or your user interaction anyways.

Hope this answers your Question ^^

Comment: would it be better for me to just call the variable under an ID value instead so I don't need to mess around with the array? I just want this same cancel button to work the same everywhere I use them.

Comment: Yes if you need to distinguish which of the buttons the user clicks (e.g. you have three close buttons that do different stuff) it would be preferable to use different IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The value in brackets is indicating the index of an array.

This statement:

`document.getElementsByClassName("close")`

returns an array of elements in your document with the class name "close". If there are multiple close buttons it would return an array of all of those elements.

Adding `[0]` to the end of that statement means you are selecting the element at the starting index of the array (the first element in the array).

You could change that to `[1]` and it would select the second element within that array, but this doesn't help you in this situation.

If you want to close multiple modals with the same close button and there is only one close button with the class name 'close' than you can always select that button with:

`document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DylanStark . But how come if I repeat the same button on other windows, it won't work the same? Does that mean I need to declare different variables for different windows?